# netbeans project reference issues

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two project: Test1 and Test2. Test 2 has a script to test project folder:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
```

result is:

```
/home/andy/Documents/Project/Test2/build/classes/
```

When Test2 added Test1 into compile-time libraries:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()
```

result is:

```
/home/andy/Documents/Project/Test1/build/classes/
```

So my question is:
Why the path is not still `/home/andy/Documents/Project/Test2/build/classes/` after I added Test1 into compile-time libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting a classloader, more specifically the classloader that was used to load Test2.class. After that you ask the classloader to get you a resource. The default behaviour for classloaders is to ask the parent classloader, if it can resolve the request. Since you will not have a parent classloader the bootstrap classloader of your jvm will be used. When asking it for a resource with an empty name, it can satisfy this with the first entry of the classpath. Depending on how NetBeans configures the classpath this can be either Test1 or Test2.

If you want to have a deterministic result, specify a resource from either project, which is unique to the project.

Comment: I have changed to test2.Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath(); the result is still same: /home/andy/Documents/Project/Test1/build/classes/, while test2 is a package name and Main is the class name, how can fix it?

Comment: Anyone have idea? Is it belongs to a bug in NetBeans 8.1? I must make project reference, otherwise it is very trouble to import different *.jar, so please help me, thx!

Comment: Load a resource that belongs to the corresponding project. For example ```getResource("fileProject1.txt")```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at maas.server.https.SecureServer.getPath(SecureServer.java:93)
 at maas.server.https.SecureServer.start(SecureServer.java:38)
 at maas.Main.main(Main.java:12)                                       even if getResource("name.txt") or getResource("./name.txt")

Comment: Do you actually have a resource "name.txt" in the project and is it available on the classpath of the project?

Comment: I fixed the issues, i need to make full path from src that getResource("xxx/xxx/xxx/fileProject1.txt") something like that...